# Error - dataprovider must return either Object[][] or Iterator&lt;Object&gt;[], not class [[Ljava.lang.Object;

Tags: java, selenium, webdriver, testng

I am getting an error while trying to read data from excel sheet. My environment  is  - poi 3.10 jar, java 1.8 , window

```
[Error] org.testng.TestNGException: 
Data Provider public static java.lang.Object[][] mytestpackage.DataProvi.CustomerCreation() throws java.lang.Exception must return either Object[][] or Iterator&lt;Object&gt;[], not class [[Ljava.lang.Object;
    at org.testng.internal.MethodInvocationHelper.invokeDataProvider(MethodInvocationHelper.java:133)
```

Here is my dataprovider code

```
   @DataProvider

    public static Object[][] CustomerCreation() throws Exception{

         Object[][] testObjArray = ExcelUtils.getTableArray("E://TT//src//utility//TestData.xlsx","Sheet1");

         return (testObjArray);

        }
```

Code for dataprovider implementation :

```
@Test(dataProvider="CustomerCreation")

    public void Registration_data(String Sr, String ssn) throws  Exception{
```

Please let me know where i am making a mistake

Excel Utility Code :-

```
package utility;

import java.io.Closeable;
import java.io.FileInputStream;
import java.util.Iterator;

import org.apache.poi.ss.usermodel.Cell;
import org.apache.poi.ss.usermodel.Row;
import org.apache.poi.xssf.usermodel.XSSFCell;
import org.apache.poi.xssf.usermodel.XSSFRow;
import org.apache.poi.xssf.usermodel.XSSFSheet;
import org.apache.poi.xssf.usermodel.XSSFWorkbook;

public class ExcelUtils {

    private static XSSFSheet ExcelWSheet;

    private static XSSFWorkbook ExcelWBook;

    private static XSSFCell Cell;

    private static XSSFRow Row;

public static  Object[][] getTableArray(String FilePath, String SheetName) throws Exception {   

   String[][] tabArray = null;



       try {
        FileInputStream ExcelFile = new FileInputStream(FilePath);

           // Access the required test data sheet

           ExcelWBook = new XSSFWorkbook(ExcelFile);

           ExcelWSheet = ExcelWBook.getSheet(SheetName);


           Iterator<Row> iterator = ExcelWSheet.iterator();

           while (iterator.hasNext()) {
               Row nextRow = iterator.next();
               Iterator<Cell> cellIterator = nextRow.cellIterator();

               while (cellIterator.hasNext()) {
                   Cell cell = cellIterator.next();

                   int cellType = cell.getCellType();
                if (cellType == Cell.CELL_TYPE_STRING) {
                    System.out.print(cell.getStringCellValue());
                } else if (cellType == Cell.CELL_TYPE_BOOLEAN) {
                    System.out.print(cell.getBooleanCellValue());
                } else if (cellType == Cell.CELL_TYPE_NUMERIC) {
                    System.out.print(cell.getNumericCellValue());
                }
                   System.out.print(" - ");
               }
               System.out.println();
           }

         //  ExcelWBook.close();
           ExcelFile.close();
    } catch (Exception e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    return tabArray;



   }

}
```

Test Data in excel;

I dont know how to do an attachment so here is one row of data

```
808088336   FIRSTNAME   D   8336LASTNAME    10053 Climbing Tree St  Conroe  77396   111 111 111 1234    361 361 1184    9890123456  FIRSTNAME.8336LASTNAME@CONNS.COM
```

Comment: please share `ExcelUtils` class code.

Comment: Thanks for reply Naveen, Just added Excel Utility code . Please check a code.

Comment: please also add the `TestData.xlsx` file. I tried with above code. but getting some other error saying `Caused by: org.apache.poi.openxml4j.exceptions.InvalidFormatException: Package should contain a content type part [M1.13]`

Comment: Which TestNG version do you use? Could you try with the latest (6.10)?

Comment: I am using 3.10 version of poi. I do got the similar issue openxml4j.jar was missing . please by adding this jar

Comment: Your data provider is returning null